# Showing that a Integral Equation has a clear solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to proof that the equation
$y(x)=x+\epsilon\int_0^\pi \sin(y(x)) dx $
has a clear solution (in $C([0,2\pi])$), assuming $\epsilon$ is "small enough".

I tried to argue with the Picard Lindelöf theorem, but the $\epsilon$ is confusing me a little bit.

Tanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Contraction mapping theorem. Define:
$$F : C^0([0,2\pi]) \rightarrow C^0([0,2\pi])$$
$$ f \mapsto F(f)$$
where $F(f)(x) := x + \epsilon \int_0^\pi \sin(f(x))dx$ and let $||\cdot||_\infty$ be the infinity norm on $C([0,2\pi])$.
Let us prove that $F$ is a contraction:
$$|F(f)(x) - F(g)(x)| \leq \epsilon \int_0^\pi |\sin(f(x)) - \sin(g(x))|dx$$
taking into account that $|\sin(f(x)) - \sin(g(x))| \leq |f(x) - g(x)|$ and passing to the supremum we get
$$||F(f) - F(g)||_\infty \leq \epsilon \pi ||f - g||_\infty$$
Now take $\epsilon < \frac{1}{\pi}$ and apply the Contraction mapping theorem which guarantees that there exists a unique fixed point of $F$ which is a solution of your equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is
$$
y(x)=x+Cϵ
$$
with
$$
C=\int_0^\pi\sin(y(x))\,dx=\int_0^\pi\sin(x+Cϵ)\,dx=2\cos(Cϵ)
$$
which has a solution $C=2-4ϵ^2+O(ϵ^4)$ for small $ϵ$.